# Java Mail api: Read only latest replied message from mail body

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am using JavaMail api to read the mail, but I am facing problem while reading message from the replied mail.

> This the the new reply
>
> From: recipient Admin [mailto:test1@test.net]
>   Sent: 08 August 2016 19:04
>   To: abcd@test.COM
>   Subject: commented  for test

I want to read only the replied message  i.e"this is the new reply",
using

```
  Multipart mp = (Multipart)p.getContent();
```

gives me the entire mail with the salutations of the sender as well, I want to just read the replied mail and not previous mail salutations.
I don't want differentiate on the basis on  specific string as each mailing service would have different salutations.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you do a bit of searching, you'll find that there's no simple solution to this problem.  There is no standard for how the original message is embedded in the reply message and thus no standard way to extract it.  The only solution is heuristics that handle the most common forms, but there's no guaranteed way to handle all possible cases.